# Preserving end of line characters when scraping a multiple line attribute string with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping values from an address attribute that has a string which is three lines.  When I use the below code, the end of lines are not preserved which means I cannot parse it further to extract the City and Zip code.

How else should I write my code so that I can preserve the end of line characters:

Here is the attribute value format:

```
John Doe
Building One
Washington, DC 20001
```

Here is the code:

```
addressTring = soup.find(id="addressID").get_text()
```

Results in output of:

```
John DoeBuilding OneWashington, DC 20001
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For some reason the initial multi-line value did not show up correctly on this site, the name, building / street name & number, and the city and state are all on separate lines.

Comment: Can you show the initial html markup?

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve].**